# breaking virtual inheritance avoiding explicit base ctor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual

Following explanation and examples from [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance) I have exemplary constructed the following inheritance model creating a diamond

```
class Base {
public:
    int data_;
    Base(int d) : data_(d) {}
    Base() = deleted;
 };

class A : public virtual Base {
public:
    A() : Base(42) {};
};

class B : public virtual Base {
public:
    B() : Base(24) {};
}

class AB : public A, public B {
public:
    AB() : Base(-1) {};
}
```

so far so good; note, that `AB()` needs to call to the `Base(int)`-ctor now. This is kind of understandable, because having the alternative initializer branches of going through AB>>A>>Base or AB>>B>>Base would not result in a well defined behavior at that.

Lets branch out from class `A` into a side-branch before we even have closed the diamond:

```
class A_Child : public A {
public:
    A_Child() : A() {}; // not permitted by compiler
}
```

This will not compile, as the compiler will explicitly ask for to specify the ctor `Base(int)` in the inializer list of `A_Child`.

I don't quite understand this behavior; as we are no longer virtually inheriting at this point and the path of initalization of A_Child>>A>>Base is not ambiguous.

It seems now for every furthermore derived class of `A_Child` I have to again specify the `Base(int)` initializer explicitly. This is kind of breaking the encapsulation as every code that derives from this class needs to know how the class at the very base acts and is implemented.

Is there any way to stop or to break the virtual inheritance once I branch into a side-line?

Comment: This is explained in the very page you link to yourself: _"The thing you as a programmer need to know is this: constructors for virtual base classes **anywhere in your class’s inheritance hierarchy are called by the “most derived” class’s constructor.**"_ and _Practically speaking, this means that when you create a concrete class that has a virtual base class, you must be prepared to pass whatever parameters are required to call the virtual base class’s constructor._.

Comment: virtual inheritance is extremely convoluted. Do you self a solid and redesign your hierarchy to avoid this.

Comment: Normally virtual inheritance goes with virtual functions; if you *inherit* from `A`, you already need to be aware of the `Base` interface.  I can see how “locally virtual inheritance” could be useful in some cases, though.

Comment: @dfrib I have indeed read and understood the essence of the forementioned citation (I can also just observe it in the given example). However, the mechanics are not quite clear to me: As long as there is no second virtual Base-class merging into the line of inheritance from the side, the path of inheritance is quite linear and unambiguous. Thus, the compiler could treat the inheritance up to any concrete class in the chain as a solved problem (a block) and so treat all further decedents as classes without virtual inheritance. kind of 'local virtual inheritance' as mentioned by >Davis Herring