# Expressing virtual ancestors in multilevel inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

With virtual inheritance it is the most derived object's obligation to initialize not only direct base clases, but all `virtual` ancestor classes as well.

As an example, consider the following class hierarchy (minding that `struct`s use `public` inheritance by default):

```cpp
struct B {
    B() = delete;
    B(int);
};
struct D1 : virtual B {
    D1(int x) : B(x) {}
};
struct D2 : virtual B {
    D2(int x) : B(x) {}
};
```

If I were to intoduce a class `D12` like this...

```cpp
struct D12 : D1, D2 {
    D12(int x) : D1(x), D2(x) {}
};
```

Compilation would fail, as `D12` has to initialize `B` and because it doesn't do that, the compiler assumes that the default constructor (which is deleted) is supposed to be invoked. The solution would be to manually invoke the `B::B(int)` constructor:

```cpp
struct D12 : D1, D2 {
    D12(int x) : B(x), D1(x), D2(x) {}
};
```

I see a problem in that solution. The problem is that the declaration of class `D1` does not contain either `B` or `virtual`. To properly implement this class we must somehow know that the classes `D1` and `D2` inherit from a virtual base class `B`. One could say that it should be assumed that if we use multiple inheritance than we will have to initialize some virtual base classes. However the problem persists when only seemingly using regular inheritance:

```cpp
struct D : D1 {
    // D still has to initialize B
    D(int x) : B(x), D1(x) {}
};
```

As a sort of workaround I thought that maybe I could make `D` also inherit from `B` (virtually) to at least express this hidden dependency in the declaration:

```cpp
struct D : virtual B, D1 {
    D(int x) : B(x), D1(x) {}
};
```

Is this guaranteed to be equivalent to the previous code? Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you really need non-default constructor for virtual base? (I mostly see virtual inheritance needed with (pure) interfaces, so default constructor would be fine there).

Comment: you must know your base class. `virtual` or not, to construct a `D` you must know what it takes to construct a `D1`.

Comment: i would not call it "hidden". Consider a base class gets a default constructor removed. Then derived classes will break, because they did depend on the base having a default constructor. You dont know if the base class has a default constructor by looking at definition of derived, though its not "hidden", its in the definition of the base

Comment: I don't see differences (from compiler point of view) between `struct D : D1` and `struct D : virtual B, D1`. (with `struct D1 : virtual B`).

Comment: @Jarod42 I know most of the time MI is used with interfaces, but I stumbled across use case that didn't have a default constructor, like above, so I wanted to ask about that. From my own testing it also seems that the two code examples are equivalent, but I wanted to make sure about that.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of a recent [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66820935/breaking-virtual-inheritance-avoiding-explicit-base-ctor).